# Add objects in ArrayList while designing class in Java

Tags: java, oop

I'm trying to create Patient and Allergy class and I'm confused about List allergies in setAllergies, whether it should be:

```
    this.allergies = allergies;
```

or

```
    allergies.add(allergies);
```

Patient class:

```
public class Patient {

    private List<Allergy> allergies;

    public List<Allergy> getAllergies() {
        return allergies;
    }

    public void setAllergies(List<Allergy> allergies) {
        this.allergies = allergies;
    }

}
```

Allergy class:

```
public class Allergy {
    private String name;
    private Severity severity;

    public Allergy(String name, Severity severity) {
        this.name = name;
        this.severity = severity;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Severity getSeverity() {
        return severity;
    }

    public void setSeverity(Severity severity) {
        this.severity = severity;
    }
}
```

Comment: `allergies.add(allergies)` makes no sense. It wouldn't even compile.

Comment: @shmosel The main confusion I do have is that Allergy class will return Allergy object then how is it getting added in the List<Allegry> by this.allergies = allergies ? From where the list of allergies will come from? As allergies is being passed as a parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
allergies.add(allergies);
```

adds a object to itself.
 Why doing that ?
Besides you cannot add a List to a List with `add()`.
 You have to use `addAll()` for that.

---

Actually the `allergies` field is `null` when a `Patient` instance is created.

As a consequence, doing it :  `allergies.invokeSomething(...);` will throw a `NullPointerException`.
Besides, the "set" prefix has a semantics to overwrite/replace, not to add.
So you should keep your method as you wrote for the moment :

```
public void setAllergies(List<Allergy> allergies) {
    this.allergies = allergies;
}
```

Now, if you want provide a way to add `Allergies` to the `Allergies` objects contained in the `allergies` field, you should provide a method `addAllergies()` :

```
public void addAllergies(List<Allergy> allergies) {
    this.allergies.addAll(allergies);
}
```

And you should also initialize the `allergies` field in its declaration (or in the constructor of `Patient`) :

```
private List<Allergy> allergies = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: The main confusion I do have is that Allergy class will return Allergy object then how is it getting added in the List<Allegry> by this.allergies = allergies ? From where the list of allergies will come from? As allergies is being passed as a parameter.

Comment: "From where the list of allergies will come from? " You have provide as arguments the allergies List that you want to set in the Patient object.For example : `Patient p = new Patient(); List<Allergy> allergies = Arrays.asList(new Allergy(...), new Allergy(...)); p.setAllergies(allergies)`

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot.